# Who created all other way of lives if God created "only one true path"?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

There are thousands of many different ways to live ones lives. Who created these ways or paths? if Islam claims that god has created only one true way of life? Is Islamic Satan more creative than Islamic god?

Comment: Could you define what you mean with "different ways to live ones life" and "the only in true way of life" just a bit to make the question more clear? Also you use the word "created", what do you mean by that?

Comment: One example of "different ways to live ones life": suppose I choose to do idol worship which is a way of life now the islam will say no it is wrong  and claim that what islam is saying is "the only true way of life", else there would be consequences. Further "the way or path to follow is dictated by Islamic god in quran" is considered as created as anything comes in existence is created by a creator, so all the other ways are created by whom?

Comment: If Satan was so creative why Allah clearly show in the qur'an in what ways Satan may corrupt people.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If you write your daily diary who will be hero and about whom you will write flaws and about whom you clearly show in your dairy in what way other person may corrupt your allegiance. Even if you would be villain in overall scheme of things, what would you write in your dairy? Any path which exists must has creation inherently attached to it(existence and creation are almost same at initial level) , somany paths exists in nature, but you write about path that you experienced in your diary, that makes other paths false and people travelling on that path as Satan?

Answer (score 0):

The other 'religions' are corruptions innovated by those who were misguided themselves or wished to misguide others - the devils among men and jinn included.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It means that Islamic Satan is more creative than Islamic god as there is one Islam and there are multiple diff cultures like dinka, shintoism, Taoism, etc.

Comment: @Ablex lols ... where did you pick up such a flawless sense of logic? What Islamic God does is not a measure of the limit of what he can do. The simple fact is that there is one truth and a thousand lies that can be told against it.  Our God does not lie - that does not make him less creative.

Comment: So when you say our god not lie, you are restricting your god with mundane human conditions of lying or telling truth? As after being restricted, how your god chooses that what he is saying is true and other gods are false, just by saying that what he is saying is true and that his prime ego is cause of it or what is the foundation of his judgement of true and false?